# Export comments from Differential code review in Phabricator

Tags: phabricator

Is there a way to get the comments received for a code-review commit in a pre-push code review in a spreadsheet format?

This is necessary for metrics calculations (number of lines of code vs number of comments received).

Is there a plugin for this?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no such option.

More details 
https://secure.phabricator.com/T5873